Lagrangian duals for the generalized assignment problem
I'm new to integer programming and I'm reading the book GTM 271: Integer Programming written by Michele Conforti, Gerard Cornuejols and Giacomo Zambelli.
I have trouble solving exercise 8.6:
Consider two different Lagrangian duals for the generalized assignment problem
\begin{align*}
z_I = \max &\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}x_{ij} \\
&\sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij} \le 1 \qquad i=1,\dots,m \\
&\sum_{i=1}^m a_{j}x_{ij} \le b_{j} \qquad j=1,\dots,n \\
&x_{ij}\in\{0, 1\} \qquad i=1,\dots,m,j=1,\dots,n
\end{align*}
Discuss the relative merits of these two duals based on (i) the strength of
the bound, (ii) ease of solution of the subproblems.

There are two natural choices for dualization.  Dualize either the first set of constraints, yielding a knapsack subproblem, or the second set of constraints, yielding a trivial subproblem that satisfies the integrality property.
